# When I edit the code in a TextArea using CodeMirror how to reflect this into another textarea with js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, codemirror

**The App:** I have a textarea element in my page. It is transformed using CodeMirror, because I need to indent and highlight html code withing it. Pic is in the link:
[textarea using codemirror]

http://uploadingit.com/file/gxftd2cps9wm7zhp/cm.png

Here is the code for textarea using codemirror:

```
</textarea>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>       
</form>
 <script>

   var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
     mode: { name: "xml", htmlMode: true },
     lineNumbers: true,
     tabMode: "indent",
     matchBrackets: true,
     path: 'js/', 
     searchMode: 'inline',
     onCursorActivity: function () {
       editor.setLineClass(hlLine, null);
       hlLine = editor.setLineClass(editor.getCursor().line, "activeline");
     }
   });

   var hlLine = editor.setLineClass(0, "activeline");
  </script>
```

**How to do it?:** When I click Post button, all the code should be transmitted to another textarea. I need this to do with javascript or jQuery, but struggling how to do it. Any Help?

**For the real world app** the code in this textarea (from pic above) should affect the Html Designer API. i.e. Any changes in Html designer should be reflected in this textarea (which used codemirror for readability) and the opposite. When I edit in the textarea changes should be reflected in HtmlDesigner, but in this simulation case -> in the second textarea.

**Example:** like Visual Studio .Net WebPage Code Editor which has Designer + Source mode. Now it's clear?

**I'm asking** how to implement the mechanism described above using javascript or jquery. Thank you much!

Answer (score 39):

Pass an onChange option to CodeMirror which looks something like this:

```js
onChange: function (cm) {
   mySecondTextArea.value = cm.getValue();
}
```

Edited to note: Since CodeMirror version 2.0, you don't pass an `onChange` option anymore to register a change handler, but call `instance.on("change", function(cm, change) { ... })` instead. http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_change

Comment: Wow! So glad to hear it from the author :) But still misunderstanding: 1. I need to write another this new function (cm)? 2. mySecondTextArea can be a simple textarea or yet another using cm in order to work.

Comment: The Scenario: I insert code in a simple textarea. When I press Post button that code should go to the textarea that uses code mirror so it could be edited nicely. After editing, again, when pressing another Save Changes button the code should appear changed in the first textarea (like in an IDE playground:)).

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question. But whats the funtions and code for this mechanism in js? I do surf the web and books for js but this time need it quicker. :) Thx.

Comment: http://codemirror.net/manual.html - onChange (function)
    When given, this function will be called every time the content of the editor is changed. It will be given the editor instance as only argument.

Comment: Has the API changed since this comment? Using `{ onChange : function(cm) { alert("foo"); } }` doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 25):

Last released version at moment (v 3.15) works with this solution:

```
// on and off handler like in jQuery
CodemirrorInstance.on('change',function(cMirror){
  // get value right from instance
  yourTextarea.value = cMirror.getValue();
});
```

Answer (score 18):

This works work CodeMirror 5.22.0:

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('grammar'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'pegjs',
}).on('change', editor => {
    console.log(editor.getValue());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

onChange handling in code mirror is not like this :

```
onChange: function(cm) { mySecondTextArea.value = cm.getValue(); }
```

you have to use :

```
$.fn.buildCodeMirror = function(){
    var cmOption {...};
    var cm = CodeMirror($("MyDomObjectSelector")[0],cmOption);
    cm.on("change",$.fn.cmChange);
}

$.fn.cmChange = function(cm,cmChangeObject){
    alert("code mirror content has changed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to copy text from one TextArea (which renders as an `input` control, by the way) to another?

```
//Set the button to call a Javascript function when it is clicked
<button type="submit" onclick="copyText();">Post</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyText() {
        //Get the text in the first input
        var text = document.getElementById("firstTextArea").getValue(); 
        //Can't use .value here as it returns the starting value of the editor

        //Set the text in the second input to what we copied from the first
        document.getElementById("secondTextArea").value = text;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Code appears in the second textarea from first only when I put code inside textarea in visual studio. But in a real world the user of the site will insert some code on first textarea and that should appear in the second txtarea in order to edit it then on pressing Post button. It should go to the first. So how to detect what user inserted and how to take control with JS of that? :) Thx.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting...  are you clicking on the button while the textarea is still selected?  If so, try clicking out of the text area (so it blurs) before clicking on the button.  If it still doesn't work properly then I would assume that it's a CodeMirror feature that's returning the old value instead of the new one - trying getValue() as suggested by Marijn might be a good idea.

Comment: Ah yes, use getValue() - http://codemirror.net/manual.html - .value is the starting value of the editor.  I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Highly appreciate it! I'm learning on the way with you geeks.

Comment: That's how it works :)  Remember to accept an answer once you've go the correct one ;)  Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This ...

```
var editor_js = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("js"), {
   mode: 'text/javascript',
   theme: 'icecoder',
   styleActiveLine: true,
   lineNumbers: true,
   lineWrapping: true,
});
```

And Get Data With
`editor_js.getValue()`